# Can SagePay link and automaically download web orders?

Tags: opayo

I am looking at changing from WorldPay to SagePay. I am looking to change because i have been told by using SagePay I can link it to my Sellerdeck website and automatically transfer web orders straight to our Sage 50 account package rather than entering them all manually. I then phoned SagePay to apply and i was then told this could not be done! I have since spoken to somebody else at Sage and they have said it can be done. So if anyone can help me out that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Check out:

http://www.sagepay.co.uk/file/2291/download-document/Sage_50_and_Instant_2014_User_Guide.pdf

abc